# Why would this code give a segfault only for some cases?

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, subset-sum

I am trying to code a Word-RAM version of the subset sum. (It is a basic dp algorithm, and the algo itself should not be important to determine the problem with the code). This is the minimum code needed to reproduce the error I think:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>


// get bit #bitno from num. 0 is most significant.
unsigned int getbit(unsigned int num, int bitno){

    unsigned int w = sizeof(int)*8;  //for regular word.
    int shiftno = w-bitno-1;
    unsigned int mask = 1<<shiftno;
    unsigned int maskedn = num&mask;
    unsigned int thebit = maskedn>>shiftno;
    return thebit;
}

/* No boundary array right shift */
unsigned int* nbars(unsigned int orig[], unsigned int x){

    int alength = sizeof(orig)/sizeof(orig[0]);
    unsigned int b_s = sizeof(int)*8;
    unsigned int * shifted;
    shifted = new unsigned int[alength];
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<alength;i++){
        shifted[i] = 0;
    }

    unsigned int aux1 = 0;
    unsigned int aux2 = 0;

    int bts = floor(x/b_s);
    int split = x%b_s;
    i = bts;
    int j = 0;
    while(i<alength){
        aux1 = orig[j]>>split;
        shifted[i] = aux1|aux2;
        aux2 = orig[j]<<(b_s-split);
        i++;j++;
    }

    return shifted;
}

/* Returns true if there is a subset of set[] with sum equal to t */
bool isSubsetSum(int set[],int n, int t){
    unsigned int w = sizeof(int)*8;  //for regular word.
    unsigned int wordsneeded = ceil(double(t+1)/w);
    unsigned int elements = n;
    //Create table
    unsigned int table[elements][wordsneeded];
    int c,i;
    //Initialize first row
    for(i=0;i<wordsneeded;i++){
        table[0][i] = 0;
    }
    table[0][0] = 1<<(w-1);
    //Fill the table in bottom up manner
    int es,ss,ai;
    for(c=1;c<=elements; c++){

        unsigned int *aux = nbars(table[c-1],set[c-1]);
        for(i=0;i<wordsneeded;i++){
            table[c][i] = table[c-1][i]|aux[i];
        }
        }

    if((table[elements][wordsneeded-1]>>((w*wordsneeded)-t-1))&1 ==1){

         return true;
     }return false;
}


int main(){


    int set[] = {81,80,43,40,30,26,12,11,9};
    //int sum = 63;
    int sum = 1000;

    int n = sizeof(set)/sizeof(set[0]);
    if (isSubsetSum(set,n,sum) == true)
     printf("\nFound a subset with given sum\n");
  else
     printf("\nNo subset with given sum\n");
  return 0;
}
```

Ok. so If I run the example with a target sum of 63, it works just fine. gives the right answer , True, and if I run code to print the subset it prints the right subset. however, if I change the sum to a larger one, say 1000 like in the code, I get the following error:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0000000000400af1 in isSubsetSum (set=0x0, n=0, t=0) at redss.cpp:63
63          unsigned int *aux = nbars(table[c-1],set[c-1]);
```

from gdb. I really don't understand why it would fail only for larger sums, since the process should be the same... am I missing something obvious? Any help would be great!!!

Comment: Well, to find out such is what debuggers were invented for. What did you observe when stepping through your code line by line? Watch `c` in particular.

Comment: Possible cause: You have a horrible memory leak.  You are using `new` without any calls to `delete`.

Comment: `int alength = sizeof(orig)/sizeof(orig[0]);` -- This does not give you the number of elements in the `orig` array.  Why?  Because `orig` is no longer an array at that point --- it is a pointer.  Consider using `std::vector` and ditch using arrays.  And **don't use variable length arrays**.  Use `std::vector`.

Comment: You do know that left shifts greater than or equal to the size of the type being shifted is undefined behaviour - right?

Comment: @OP.  I'm doing you a favor.  [Please look at this version of your code using `vector`](http://ideone.com/pS0NDQ).  Note the usage of the `at()` keyword to determine if anything goes out of bounds -- and yes, you are going out of bounds due to the `out_of_range` exception being thrown.  A variable-length-array or using `new[]` does **not** give you these advantages of 1) Determining whether you're going out of bounds and 2) Stopping the memory leaks.

Comment: @JesperJuhl no I didn't. obviously. :) Thanks for your help that's probably it actually.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Thank you for this, I'm checking this code out now !